# In Microsoft Test Manage Lab Center, where do the setup and cleanup scripts actually run?

Tags: c#, tfs, mtm

I've written a batch file to execute a TFS API console app upon the completion of a test run to reset all failed tests to active.  Where does the test script actually physically execute so I can put my .exe in the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

You  can find it in Microsoft Test Manager → Test Plan → Test Settings → Scripts
[image]
[image]

More info from MSDN:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741(v=vs.140).aspx